# Increment value inside nested objects

Tags: php, oop, object

[PHP]

I have a $cart object that (json_encoded) looks like this:

```
{"merchant_id":"5","items":[{"id":"23”,”size”:”small”,”price":"3","quantity”:1},{"id":"23”,”size":"
large","price":"3","quantity”:1},{"id":"24”,”size”:”medium”,”price":"3","quantity":1}]}
```

I'd like to increment the quantity of the item which has `id=23` and `size=large`, is there an elegant way to identify that specific value and increment it without looping through all the items and re-creating the object?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean without re-creating the object? Not using json_decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looping, but with filtering you can select the desire element.

Use `json_decode` and get data as `objects` not as `array` so can keep references.

an example is the following

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "merchant_id": "5",
    "items": [{
        "id": "23",
        "size": "small",
        "price": "3",
        "quantity": 1
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "size": "large",
        "price": "3",
        "quantity": 1
    }, {
        "id": "24",
        "size": "medium",
        "price": "3",
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}';

$cart = json_decode($json); # Decode as stdClass objects

# Filter desire element
$item = array_filter($cart->items, function ($i) {
    return $i->id == "23" && $i->size == 'large';
});

# array_filter returns array so get the first element.
# you could check if $item is false.
$item = reset($item);
# increase quantity
$item->quantity++;

# Encode json data
$json = json_encode($cart);

echo $json;
```

Comment: Perfect solution, didn't know it would update the original object!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Assuming you used json_decode, the best way I can come up with is iterating over each items, looking for the id you whose item you want to update, perform update and break the loop :

```
foreach($cart['items'] as $k => $item){
    if($item['id'] == 23){
        $cart['items'][$k]['quantity']++;
        break;
    }

    continue;
}
```

Assuming you don't want to use json_decode, you could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace), but frankly it does not have the elegance you asked for.